# Wifi List<ScanResult> information batch

Tags: android, android-studio, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

Sorry this question might be easy/confusing because I'm new to Java and Android Studio.

The android.net.wifi.ScanResult class has fields SSID/BSSID that gives the information of the scanned access point by calling ScanResult.SSID.

However, if I create List = scanresults, how should I access the information of each ScanResult in the list?
Thank you so much.

Information regarding ScanResult and RangingRequest could be found here.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult?hl=en#getInformationElements()
https://developer.android.com/static/reference/android/net/wifi/rtt/RangingRequest.Builder#addaccesspoints

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to Access each Scanresult in the list

```
private void printList(List<ScanResult> list){
    for(ScanResult result: list){
        int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(result.level, 100);
        System.out.println(result.SSID + " Level is " + level + " out of 100");
    }
}
```